# past usual events/activity

Tags: sentence-construction

How to Say past usual events/activity ?
My manager has resigned now. When he was manager he_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**.

He Signed cheques everyday
or
He would/Use to sign cheques every day.
or
He was signing cheques every day.
Or
Something else

Comment: Your first two suggestions are fine but If it was a formal routine then I am more inclined to say "He signed cheques everyday".

Comment: All of those are fine, although "he was signing cheques every day" sounds least natural in the context. I would say "used to" rather than "use to", but I think both are acceptable.

Comment: @nxx The term *use to* is inaccurate, see ["I use to or I used to"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30035/i-use-to-or-i-used-to) .

Comment: @JWLim Thanks. A few years ago I started noticing "use to" where I would have expected "used to", and it got me confused about whether there were regional usage differences I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 1):

He " used to"  sign chèques every day. "Used to" is a most useful  expression to refer to activities that were common and frequent in the past .

Answer (score 0):

We use** **used to/would*** for repeated actions or routines in the past. Therefore "besides the past perfect tense, we can also say: He **used to/would** sign cheques every day. We don't use **would** with stative verbs," I would have a pet cat", or when we are decribing situations.: "I ***used** ****to***** (not would) be fat when I was young.". Furthermore, the only case of using "used to", without a "d", is when it's in a negative or interrogative sentence. example: "I **didn't use** to go to parties when I was young./ What **did you use** to eat for breakfast." As for the last sentence, "He was signing...." ,its use is not correct here. The past progressive is used for an action which was in progress at a stated time in the past/ or when another action interrupted it. Also, for two simultaneous past actions in progress in the past, or to decribe the atmosphere, setting,etc in the introduction to a story before we describe the main events.Examples:
**I was having dinner at seven o'clock yesterday evening.
I was cooking when the phone rang.
She was doing the dishes while I was doing the housework.
One beautiful afternoon, a young boy was strolling down a country lane. The sun was shining and the birds were singing*****.
So, as you can see , in your case, the past continuous isn't correct

Answer (score -1):

"He used to sign cheques every day" is probably the usage you require.

"He would sign cheques every day" implies the manager didn't take his job seriously or enquire what the cheques were for. In other words, he was not a good manager.

Comment: To my ear, "would" does not have a negative connotation here.  "He was always signing checks" might, on the other hand.

Comment: @user2619 Unless signing checks is a bad thing, I don't see how "He was always..." can be negative.

Comment: @helix Yes, you're right.